# What is lodash library, is it required for QuillJS?

Tags: lodash, quill

I see this library included, and not much of an explanation for what it is doing. Is it required to use the QuillJS library, and if so, what does it do?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

It is referenced in an external js file with

```
_ = Quill.require('lodash');
```

Isn't it implied it is already included with the script tags above?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Lodash website](https://lodash.com/)

> Lodash makes JavaScript easier by taking the hassle out of working
> with arrays, numbers, objects, strings, etc. Lodash’s modular methods
> are great for:
>
> - Iterating arrays, objects, & strings,
> - Manipulating & testing values
> - Creating composite functions

The module provides very basic and necessary functionality which QuillJS presumably uses.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash is a very useful library to have around. It has a lot of different methods  built into it for working very efficiently with arrays of data, or objects or just about anything you can possibly imagine in the world of JavaScript.
https://lodash.com/docs

I have not seen anything in the Quilljs documentation that says Lodash is required or any steps installing Lodash beforehand.
https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/